# How to make MKScaleView with SwiftUI appear correctly on initial map load

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mkmapview

I have a SwiftUI MKMapView that I've created a UIViewRepresentable with a Coordinator and have the following in the Coordinate delegate method:

```
func mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap(_ mapView: MKMapView) {
  guard scaleView != nil else {
    let scale = MKScaleView(mapView: mapView)
    scale.scaleVisibility = .visible
    scale.frame = CGRect(x: 12, y: mapView.frame.height - 90, width: mapView.frame.width / 3.0, height: 24)
    mapView.addSubview(scale)
    self.scaleView = scale
    return
  }
}
```

Essentially, I only want to add the scale view once on initial load and cannot do this in makeUIView as the view has no valid frame at that point, so am doing it in mapVieweDidFinishLoadingMap delegate method.

This code displays the scale view incompletely on initial load, but once the user interacts with the map it appears correctly.  I must not be initializing something correctly that gets handled by MapKit once the user interacts with it, but what exactly is causing it to not appear correctly on initial load before user interaction?

Comment: If you want the scale to be part of the map view, don't use MKScaleView; instead, set the map view's `showsScale` to `true`. MKScaleView is only for when you want the scale _outside_ the map view as part of _your_ view hierarchy.

Comment: I started there, but is there a way to control the location of the showsScale=true in SwiftUI?  When add a MapView().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all) to my content view with showsScale=true the scale appears under the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue, fixed it by forcing scaleView to update layout:

```
scaleView.layoutIfNeeded()
```